# Find the Point C given 2 points and a distance in a 2 dimensional space.

Tags: geometry

Given 2 points within a 2 dimensional space, an angle and a given value `Distance`. I need to generate a point B that intersects between Point A and Point C. Whereas the distance from Point A to B to C equals value `Distance`. Example values:

```
Point A = 2,6
Point C = 8,4
Distance = 9
```

Some assumptions:

- `Distance` is number that equals or is larger than the line between Point A and Point C
- The angle is randomly generated and points to Point C
- Point C is not directly connected to Point A

What formula is required to achieve this?

Comment: You are using terms that are not clear - a point can not intersect between points.

Comment: Do you know how to calculate distance between two points?

Answer (score 1):

First, 2D Euclidean distance between point $\mathbf{A} = (x_A , y_A)$ and $\mathbf{B} = (x_B , y_B)$ is
$$L_{AB} = \left\lVert \overline{\mathbf{A} \mathbf{B}} \right\rVert = \sqrt{ (x_B - x_A)^2 + (y_B - y_A)^2 }$$
where $\overline{\mathbf{A} \mathbf{B}}$ represents the vector from $\mathbf{A}$ to $\mathbf{B}$, $[x_B - x_A, y_B - y_A]^T$.

Second, angle $\varphi$ between two vectors $\overline{\mathbf{A} \mathbf{B}}$ and $\overline{\mathbf{B} \mathbf{C}}$ is
$$\cos\varphi = \displaystyle\frac{\overline{\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}}\cdot\overline{\mathbf{B}\mathbf{C}}}{\left\lVert\overline{\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}}\right\rVert \left\lVert\overline{\mathbf{B}\mathbf{C}}\right\rVert} = 
\frac{(x_B - x_A)(x_C - x_B) + (y_B - y_A)(y_C - y_B)}{\sqrt{(x_B - x_A)^2 + (y_B - y_A)^2}\sqrt{(x_C - x_B)^2 + (y_C - y_B)^2}}$$

This gives you two equations in two unknowns ($x_B$ and $y_B$, with $x_A$, $y_A$, $x_C$, $y_C$ and $\varphi$ (and therefore $\cos\varphi$) known).

We can square the latter function,
$$\frac{\bigr( (x_B - x_A)(x_C - x_B) + (y_B - y_A)(y_C - y_B) \bigr)^2}{ \bigr( (x_B - x_A)^2 + (y_B - y_A)^2 \bigr)\bigr( (x_C - x_B)^2 + (y_C - y_B)^2 \bigr) } = (\cos\varphi)^2$$
and solve it for $y_B$, then substitute those $y_B$ to the first equation, to solve for $x_B$.  These give you the candidate $(x_B, y_B)$ points (as these are for $\varphi = 90^o \pm \theta$, i.e. $\lvert\cos\varphi\rvert = T$).  Drop any points that do not fulfill both equations, and you are left with the solution points.

---

You can usually simplify the problem by a linear transform (rotation and scaling) where $(x_A, y_A)$ moves to origin, $(x_C, y_C)$ to $(1, 0)$.  Every point $(x_\text{old} , y_\text{old})$ is transformed to the new coordinate system $(x_\text{new}, y_{new})$ using
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
x_\text{new} &= \displaystyle \frac{ (y_\text{old} - y_A)(y_C - y_A) + (x_\text{old} - x_A)(x_C - x_A)}{ (x_C - x_A)^2 + (y_C - y_A)^2 } \\
y_\text{new} &= \displaystyle \frac{ (y_\text{old} - y_A)(x_C - x_A) - (x_\text{old} - x_A)(y_C - y_A) }{ (x_C - x_A)^2 + (y_C - y_A)^2 } \\
\end{aligned} \right.$$
and inversely,
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
x_\text{old} &= x_A + x_\text{new} ( x_C - x_A ) - y_\text{new} ( y_C - y_A ) \\
y_\text{old} &= y_A + x_\text{new} ( y_C - y_A ) + y_\text{new} ( x_C - x_A ) \\
\end{aligned}\right.$$
Distances are transformed using
$$\begin{aligned}
L_{new} &= \frac{L_{old}}{\sqrt{ (x_C - x_A)^2 + (y_C - y_A)^2 }} \\
L_{old} &= L_{new}\sqrt{ (x_C - x_A)^2 + (y_C - y_A)^2 } \\
\end{aligned}$$

---

Let's say you were instead looking for point $\mathbf{B} = (x_B , y_B)$ that is one the line passing through points $\mathbf{A} = (x_A , y_A)$ and $\mathbf{C} = (x_C , y_C)$, so that $$\left\lVert\overline{\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}}\right\rVert + \left\lVert\overline{\mathbf{B}\mathbf{C}}\right\rVert = 9, \quad \left\lVert\overline{\mathbf{A}\mathbf{C}}\right\rVert \lt 9$$
Then, point $\mathbf{B}$ would be outside the line segment between $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{C}$, but still on the line.

We can use parameter $t$ to specify that point:
$$\mathbf{B} = (1-t) \mathbf{A} + t \mathbf{C} = \mathbf{A} + t \left(\mathbf{C} - \mathbf{A}\right)$$
i.e.
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
x_B &= x_A + t (x_C - x_A) \\
y_B &= y_A + t (y_C - y_A) \\
\end{aligned}\right.$$
When $t = 0$, $\mathbf{B} = \mathbf{A}$.  When $t = 1$, $\mathbf{B} = \mathbf{C}$. On the line segment between $\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{C}$, $0 \le t \le 1$.
We also have
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
L_{AB} &= \left\lvert t \right\rvert L_{AC} \\
L_{BC} &= \left\lvert 1 - t \right\rvert L_{AC} \\
\end{aligned} \right.$$

In this case, the problem is to find $t$ so that the sum distance is $9$:
$$L_{AB} + L_{BC} = 9$$
this simplifies to
$$\left\lvert t \right\rvert L_{AC} + \left\lvert 1 - t \right\rvert L_{AC} = 9$$
and to
$$\left\lvert t \right\rvert + \left\lvert 1 - t \right\rvert = \frac{9}{L_{AC}}$$
It turns out that this type of equation,
$$\left\lvert t \right\rvert + \left\lvert 1 - t \right\rvert = L$$
is true for all $0 \le t \le 1$ if $L = 1$.  For $L \gt 1$, $L \in \mathbb{R}$, there are two solutions:
$$t = \frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{L}{2}$$

In this particular case, $L_{AC} = 2 \sqrt{10} \approx 6.325$, so $9/L_{AC} \gt 1$, and we have
$$\left\lvert t \right\rvert + \left\lvert 1 - t \right\rvert = \frac{9}{2\sqrt{10}} \approx 1.423$$
and the solutions are
$$t = \frac{1}{2} \pm \frac{9}{2 \sqrt{10}}$$
corresponding to points
$$\mathbf{B} = \begin{cases}
(13.538, 2.154), & t \approx 1.923 \\
(-3.538, 7.846), & t \approx -0.923 \\
\end{cases}$$

---

If point $\mathbf{C}$ is at direction $\theta$ from $\mathbf{B}$, with $\theta = 0$ on the positive $x$ axis, and increasing counterclockwise, then we can use
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
x_B &= x_C - r \cos \theta \\
y_B &= y_C - r \sin \theta \\
\end{aligned} \right .$$
with $\mathbf{B}$ being at distance $r$ from $\mathbf{C}$.

In this case, the problem simplifies to
$$\sqrt{(x_B - x_A)^2 + (y_B - y_A)^2} + r = 9$$
which we need to solve for $0 \lt r \lt 9$, i.e.
$$\sqrt{(x_C - x_A - r\cos\theta)^2 + (y_C - y_A - r\sin\theta)^2} = 9 - r$$
Squaring both sides we get
$$(x_C - x_A - r\cos\theta)^2 + (y_C - y_A - r\sin\theta)^2 = r^2 - 18 r + 9^2$$
which simplifies to
$$r = \frac{ (x_C - x_A)^2 + (y_C - y_A)^2 - 9^2}{ 2 (y_C - y_A) \sin\theta  + 2 (x_C - x_A) \cos\theta - 18 }$$
and in this case to
$$r = \frac{41}{4 \sin\theta - 12\cos\theta + 18}$$
When you do know $r$ – remember to only use $0 \lt r \le 9$, as $r \lt 0$ are in the wrong direction, $r \gt 9$ are impossible (further than the desired sum distance), $r = 0$ corresponds to $\mathbf{B} = \mathbf{C}$ and $r = 9$ corresponds to $\mathbf{B} = \mathbf{A}$ –, use
$$\left\lbrace ~ \begin{aligned}
x_B &= x_C - r \cos \theta \\
y_B &= y_C - r \sin \theta \\
\end{aligned} \right .$$
to find out the coordinate(s) of the solution point(s).